# can I use flex4.6 with flex sd 4.9?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I don't want to switch to Flash Builder 4.7 since there is no graphical builder IDE.

**My question is:** 
can I use Flash Builder 4.6 with the [Apache Flex 4.9.1](https://blogs.apache.org/flex/entry/apache_flex_4_9_1)?

I added the Flex 4.9.1 SDK to my SDKs folders and I got an error:

```
unable to open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.9.1\frameworks\{airHome}\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc'
```

Comment: You're confused.  Flex is an SDK / UI Framework / Component Library.  Flash Builer is an IDE for creating Flex based applications.  They are not the same thing.  I would expect Apache Flex 4.9.1 with Flash Builder 4.6; although I would not expect the design builder to work; as that is supposedly problematic with different version of Flex.

Comment: I suppose one clarification.  Apache Flex cannot distribute proprietary Adobe runtime files such as Adobe AIR related binaries.  Did you use the Apache Flex Installer or build from the source yourself?

Comment: I want to use the Adobe IDE with newest versions of SDKs: is that possible ?

Comment: Yes; you can use the latest version of Apache Flex with Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 or Flash Builder 4.6.  I believe Flash Builder 4.7 fixes a minor bug related to moving of files from the html-template directory to the bin-debug folder.  I do not expect Design view to work w/ any version of Apache Flex.  There was a design builder prototype posted on the Apache Flex dev list a few days ago which looked promising.  I think this is the project: https://github.com/igorcosta/ApacheFlexUIBuilder